# Devise + Clearing field of Registration form when gets a validation error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, error-handling, devise

I have used `Devise gem` in my rails app. Now I have modified registration form with adding many fields like `mobile_no`, `first_name`, `last_name` etc.. now when I get validation error while submitting form `email` and `username` field remains as it is but other filled fields being cleared. I want all filled field should be as it is so user doesn't have to enter all data again. Is there any solutions..? Please help. Thanks in advance.

**app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.select(:title, Title.all.collect { |t| [t.name, t.id] } ,:include_blank=> "Select") %>

  <%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "First Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => "Last Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :suffix , :placeholder => "Suffix"%>
  </div><br>

  <div><%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div><br>

  <div><%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div><br>

  <div><%= f.label :password %>
   <%=f.password_field :password %>
   <%= link_to("Generate Password", "#")  %>
  </div><br>

  <div><%= f.label :upload_Photo %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div><br>

  <div><%= f.label :date_Of_Birth %>
   <%= f.text_field :dob, :as => :date_picker, :class => 'datepicker', :placeholder => "Click here to Select Date" %>
  </div><br>

  <div><%= f.label :role %>
    <%= select_tag(:role_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(Role.active, "id", "name"),:prompt=> "Select role") %>
  </div><br>

  <div><%= f.label :gender %>
  <%= select_tag :gender, options_for_select([['Male', 0], ['Female', 1]], :selected => :gender), :prompt => "Select gender" %></div><br>

  <div><%= f.label :address %>
  </div><br>

  <div><%= f.label :mobile_no %>
   <%= f.text_field :mobile_no  %>  
  </div><br>

  <div><%= f.label :landline_no %>
  <%= f.text_field :landline_no  %>  
  </div><br>

  <div><%= f.label :status %>
    <%= f.check_box :is_active %>
  </div><br>

  <%= f.submit %>
```

**app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  before_filter :super_admin_only, only: [ :new, :create ]
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [ :cancel ]
  #prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [ :new, :create, :cancel ]
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def super_admin_only
    redirect_to root_url if (current_admin && !current_admin.is_super_admin?) || !current_admin
  end

 def sign_up(resource_name, resource)

  @admin = Admin.new

  #sign_in(resource_name, resource)

 end

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    build_resource({})
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    #abort sign_up_params.inspect
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource_saved = resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_saved
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  def edit
    render :edit
  end

  # PUT /resource
  # We need to use a copy of the resource because we don't want to change
  # the current user in place.
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_updated
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
            :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, bypass: true
      respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
....
....
....
end
```

Any required information will be provided if you needed

Comment: what are you doing? can you post your form? Just tested, it renders extra fields filled for me

Comment: @user2675613 : updated OP

Comment: did you override devise registrations create method? if you did can you post that as well?

Comment: @user2675613 : updated controller as well..plz check

Comment: Strange i have same code in else block and it works for me. Which browser are you using? I tested it in chrome and firefox, rendering all the fields except password

Comment: @user2675613: firefox 12